# Assembly x86 control flow

Tags: assembly, control-flow

I'm having trouble writing a simple program which should find the smallest number in a stack, and leave the stack only containing this number. 0 marks the end of the stack, and should not count as a number. It seems there is a problem with the control flow. I have also tried using 
cmp a, b
jle update
instead, but with same results: the program just continues in loop, without exiting nor updating the smallest number.

main

```
push 0 ; 
push 7 ;
push 2 ; 
push 8 ; 
push 5 ; 
push 4 ; 

data a
data b
pop b

loop:
    pop a
    je a, zero, done
    jle a, b, update
    jmp loop

update:
    add b, a, zero
    jmp loop

done:
    push b
    jmp theend
```

theend:
end main

Comment: What assembler is this??? And what CPU? Provide the corresponding architecture tag.

Comment: http://www8.cs.umu.se/~ola/Dark/

I assume its x86

Comment: There is no such instructions in x86 architecture. For example all branches (jl, jle, je, etv.) have only one argument - the address where to jump if the condition is true.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is slightly modified. The documentation is only in swedish. But if I replaced "je a, zero, done" with "cmp a, zero | je done" and so forth, would there be a problem with the code if it was true x86?

Comment: Well, if you want to get an answer, you should use а syntax understandable for most people. Or at least for the one that will give you an answer. ;)

Comment: x86 `pop` instruction doesn't affect the flags (unless you are popping the flags with `popf`), so your conditional check after the `pop` will always yield the same results. After `pop a` you need to do `test a,a` or `cmp a,0` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you want is this:

```
; a and b are defined as 16-bit words
; if you're using 32-bit, you probably want
; to use 'dd' instead.
a dw 0
b dw 0

pop b

loop:
    pop a
    or a,a  ; Sets the Z flag if a is 0
    je done
    cmp a,b ; compares a and b, and sets flags
    jle  update
    jmp loop

update:
    add b, a
    jmp loop

done:
    push b
    jmp theend
```

Note also that you can change this:

```
    jle update
    jmp loop
update:
```

to this:

```
    jg loop  ; jump greater
update:
```